# Comparing values in a Python dict of lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict of lists with numbers as keys and lists of strings as values. E.g.,

```
my_dict = {
    1: ['bush', 'barck obama', 'general motors corporation'],
    2: ['george bush', 'obama'],
    3: ['general motors', 'george w. bush']
}
```

What I want is to compare each item in each list (for every key), and if the item is a substring of another item – change it to a longer one. So, kind of a very dirty coreference resolution thing.

Can't really wrap my head around how to do it.
Here's pseudo code of what I had in mind:

```
for key, value in dict:
    for item in value:
        if item is substring of other item in any other key, value:
            item = other item
```

So that my dictionary in the end will end up looking like this:

```
my_dict = {
    1: ['george w. bush', 'barck obama', 'general motors corporation'],
    2: ['george w. bush', 'barck obama'],
    3: ['general motors corporation', 'george w. bush']
}
```

Sorry if I didn't express what the problem is clearly enough.

Comment: `'george bush'` is not a substring of `'george w. bush'` so you are going to need more advanced matching if you want your expected output. BTW , `Obama's` name is `Barack`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks that's a typo that I've copy/pasted everywhere. Regarding the fact that `'george bush'` is not a substring of `'george w. bush'` – zvone's code seems to deal with that.

Comment: It does, but @zvone's (and my) code could fail for more general cases, e.g. `g. w. bush` wouldn't become `george w. bush`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that this is a dictionary of lists is irrelevant. There are strings which have to be modified depending on other strings.

These are the strings:

```
all_strings = [s for string_list in my_dict.values() for s in string_list]
```

To replace a string:

```
def expand_string(s, all_strings):
    # compare words
    matches = [s2 for s2 in all_strings
               if all(word in s2.split() for word in s.split())]
    if matches:
        # find longest result
        return sorted(matches, key=len, reverse=True)[0]
    else:
        # this wont't really happen, but anyway
        return s
```

To replace everything:

```
result = {k: [expand_string(s, all_strings) for s in v]
          for k, v in my_dict.items()}
```

Comment: FYI: `max(matches, key=len)` is equivalent to `sorted(matches, key=len, reverse=True)[0]` - without the overhead of constructing a new list.

Comment: @AChampion That's right, thanks. I never knew `max` had `key` :)

Answer (score 6):

Create a set of all the names in your dict.
Then you can create a lookup table that allows you to construct a new dict.
This uses `key=len` in the `max()` to select the longest name that has the substring:

```
>>> s = {n for v in my_dict.values() for n in v}
>>> lookup = {n: max((a for a in s if n in a), key=len) for n in s}
>>> {k: [lookup[n] for n in v] for k, v in my_dict.items()}
{1: ['george w. bush', 'barck obama', 'general motors corporation'],
 2: ['george bush', 'barck obama'],
 3: ['general motors corporation', 'george w. bush']}
```

Or you could do the `max()` in place:

```
>>> s = {n for v in my_dict.values() for n in v}
>>> {k: [max((a for a in s if n in a), key=len) for n in v] for k, v in my_dict.items()}
{1: ['george w. bush', 'barck obama', 'general motors corporation'],
 2: ['george bush', 'barck obama'],
 3: ['general motors corporation', 'george w. bush']}
```

To get your desired output you need slightly different matching criteria than just substring:

```
>>> s = {n for v in my_dict.values() for n in v}
>>> {k: [max((a for a in s if all(w in a for w in n.split())), key=len) for n in v] for k, v in my_dict.items()}
{1: ['george w. bush', 'barck obama', 'general motors corporation'],
 2: ['george w. bush', 'barck obama'],
 3: ['general motors corporation', 'george w. bush']}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I should probably learn more about list/dictionary comprehension, since these lines look very cryptic to me now.